# parallels plesk 11 missing web presence builder

Tags: plesk

After a recent upgrade to parallels plesk 11, we decided to start using their web presence builder tool. However, every video, (documentation and instructional) I have viewied shows the link should just be under websites and domains, or even on the homepage. It is in neither location.

I have verified it is both installed and up-to-date, under server -> updates and upgrades

Any idea how I access the web presence builder?

Comment: Next time you upgrade move to cPanel and your life  will be a lot easier. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for other's reference, the site builder link is hidden if your license does not support the "power pack" (godaddy, may be named different under different providers).

You can view your license by going to server -> license management

simply look for websites by web presence builder, if the value is limited to 0, you need to talk to your provider. Godaddy's upgrade was 6.99/mo